# Problems with searching two Mongo collections at once

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've got two mongo collections. The 'programs' collection has information on clients' attendance so Jane Doe may have multiple documents. The 'demographic' collection has information like address, email, phone number, etc. A client has one document in this collection. Btw, these collections are imported into Mongo via .csv files. I have a section of my app that I need to search both collections when the user clicks a button for a particular client. So, if the user selects Jane Doe, both collections are queried so that information from both collections are presented.

```
Template.clientGrid.helpers({
  'demographic': function() {
  var fullName = Session.get('clientName');
  return Demographic.find({ FullName: fullName });
  },

  'programs': function () {
     var fullName = Session.get('clientName');
     return Programs.find({FullName: fullName});
  }
});
```

There are some tiles (s) that are populated with the info that's found for Jane Doe. After the collections are queried and the tiles populated, it looks like everything is fine, except I'm finding issues with the page later. Each tile is supposed to be clickable to load a modal. But usually the modal won't load when a tile is clicked. If the user navigates away from this page, the modal will spontaneously load. The page is getting bound up somehow, even though the tiles load the information.

What I found was that if the template helper only queries one collection, the tiles load the modal when clicked. Everything's good. So it would appear that perhaps this querying of both collections is problematic the way I'm doing it. Could I code it such that I could query one collection first, then once that one finishes, query the other one? Or maybe they already are being queried in sequence and there's some other issue going on. Whatever the issue is, I need to fix it.

EDIT: Here's an example of one of the rows of tiles that populate the information:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col s4" id="roommate-change" style="background-color: #1f3a93; color: #fff; height: 275px; position: relative; top: -115px; overflow: auto;">
    <p class="grid-title">Roommate Requests:</p>
      {{#each programs}}
    <p>{{formatCampYear CampYear}}: {{formatRoommate RoomateRequest}}</p>
      {{/each}}
  </div>

  <div class="col s4" id="medicine-change" style="background-color: #2574a9; color: #fff; height: 275px; position: relative; top: -115px">
    <p class="grid-title">Medicine:</p>
      {{#each programs}}
    <p>{{MedicalCondition}}</p>
      {{/each}}
  </div>

  <div class="col s4" id="ss-info-change" style="background-color: #59abe3; color: #fff; height: 275px; position:relative; top: -115px">
    <p class="grid-title">SS Info:</p>
      {{#each demographic}}
    <p class="med-small">Mom's Name: {{MomFName}}</p>
    <p class="med-small">Dad's Name: {{DadFName}}</p>
    <p class="med-small">Mom's Phone: {{MomPhone}}</p>
    <p class="med-small">Dad's Phone: {{DadPhone}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

For the modals, I'm using the Modalize package:

```
Template.clientGrid.events({
  'click #roommate-change': function () {
    Materialize.modalize.display({
      template: 'roommateChange',
      title: 'Change Roommate Information'
    })
  },

  'click #medicine-change': function () {
     Materialize.modalize.display({
       template: 'medicalChange',
       title: 'Change Medical Related Information'
     })
  },

  'click #ss-info-change': function () {
     Materialize.modalize.display({
     template: 'ssinfoChange',
     title: 'Change SS Parent Information'
     })
   }
});
```

NOTE: Interesting find... If I comment out the demographic query in the template and only allow the programs query, the modals won't load. If I comment out the programs query and allow only the demographic query, the modals WILL load.

NOTE 2: Changing the demographic query from .find() to .findOne() doesn't work. No demographic data loads. It only works with .find(). That's weird.

MORE INFO: Here's what I found: The modals won't load based on whether or not the client is in the programs collection more than once. If Jane Doe only has one entry (or zero) in the programs collection, the modal will work. All names that are in the program collection more than once fail to load the modal. Now that I have the cause, I need to find a solution.

Comment: Querying two collections 'at once' like in your code is totally fine. Could you post more code, with 'tiles' and modals?
One more thing - you should use `Demographic.findOne(..)` instead of `Demographic.find(...)` if you expect only one document and you want to handle 'demographic' helper as one document and not an array.

Comment: If you change demographics from find() to findOne(), you need to change the corresponding #each to #with.